# How to manage view in yii?

Tags: php, yii, view

I am just starting with yii as in views layout its provides column1, column2 and main.php so when we render view it get load using these files. But we can't use same view for admin and front. I am working on admin side and want to separate header & footer of admin,so how can i manage it, any suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It is possible.
There is a wiki page in Yii for handling applications with front-end and back-end behavior. 
ie, 
there will be two folders with layout files under protected/views folder.
1. protected/views/front
2. protected/views/back

> The created behavior delivers us from specifying controllers and views paths for the application and all it's modules by using runEnd() method and invoking the onModuleCreate event in necessary places.
>
> Also modules became more self-sufficient and can be easily integrated with the existing front-end and back-end layouts.

Please go through this link http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/63/organize-directories-for-applications-with-front-end-and-back-end-using-webapplicationend-behavior/

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/63/organize-directories-for-applications-with-front-end-and-back-end-using-webapplicationend-behavior/
i am following this but its not working, i already use htaccess to remove index.php from url and as per the link URL are different so its giveing error that controller not found

Comment: Hope you had followed the exact flow described in the wiki page. Is it working with siteurl/backend.php or siteurl/index.php?

Comment: its working but now issue with loading view, i have back folder in protected > view and when i am loading view there is error "DashboardController cannot find the requested view "admin-login". " where dashboard is back end controller

Comment: protected/views/back/dashboard/admin-login.php . You need to create a "dashboard" folder.

Comment: ok, its working thank you,can't i do that without dashboard folder?

Comment: From the Yii doc, http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.view

 To render a view, call CController::render() with the name of the view. The method will look for the corresponding view file under the "directory protected/views/ControllerID".

In this case, protected/views/back/ControllerID.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by creating new layout and changing your layout in certain controller.

- create new layout in layouts folder
- write custom HTML document layout
- you should include `<?php echo $content; ?>` in your layout in right place
- override layout property in your admin(site) controller, set it to your created layout.

You can use your layout only for certain actions or for all actions in controller

See [Implement multiple layouts in application](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/28/how-to-implement-multiple-page-layouts-in-an-application/)